# Can't remove Draft watermark

Tags: draft, watermark, pnas

I'm using overleaf to create a document using the PNAS template and I have a watermark that says Draft in the background and I can't remove it. Please help.

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn,twoside]{pnas-new}
% Use the lineno option to display guide line numbers if required.
% Note that the use of elements such as single-column equations
% may affect the guide line number alignment. 

\templatetype{pnasresearcharticle} % Choose template 
% {pnasresearcharticle} = Template for a two-column research article
% {pnasmathematics} = Template for a one-column mathematics article
% {pnasinvited} = Template for a PNAS invited submission

\title{The role of  \textit{egl-1} in programmed cell death in  \textit{C. elegans} through inhibition of  \textit{ced-9} and the upstream control mechanisms}

% Use letters for affiliations, numbers to show equal authorship (if applicable) and to indicate the corresponding author
\author[a]{Thomas Munro}

\affil[a]{Department of Life Sciences, Imperial College London}

% Please give the surname of the lead author for the running footer
\leadauthor{Munro} 

% Keywords are not mandatory, but authors are strongly encouraged to provide them. If provided, please include two to five keywords, separated by the pipe symbol, e.g:
\keywords{Keyword 1 $|$ Keyword 2 $|$ Keyword 3 $|$} 

\dates{This manuscript was compiled on \today}
```

Answer (score 13):

your example file is not usable but

http://www.pnas.org/site/misc/pnas-new.cls

suggests that

```
\setboolean{displaywatermark}{false}
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much! :D (I'm a complete beginner to Latex and all this sort of stuff so sorry for the example file thing :S )

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively to Carlisle's answer, the source of the watermark is in the **.cls file** (pnas-new.cls). You can comment out all the below lines (**Ctrl + /** toggles comments for a selected block of text):

```
%% Watermark 
\newboolean{displaywatermark}
\setboolean{displaywatermark}{true} % Set to false to remove the watermark
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{displaywatermark}}{%
  \RequirePackage{draftwatermark}
  \SetWatermarkAngle{45}
  \SetWatermarkColor{gray!20}
  \SetWatermarkFontSize{3cm}
  \SetWatermarkText{{\fontfamily{bch}\bfseries DRAFT}}
}{}
}
```

p.s. you can also see the comment for how to turn it off without taking it all out right within that block of code